# How to replace all "printLog();" into "//printLog();" but not resulting "////printLog();"?

Tags: replace

for example, I want to comment out all printLog() functions in a file:

```
//printLog();
printLog();
//printLog();
```

but some printLog() are already comment out, and replacing printLog() with //printLog() directly would result in:

```
////printLog();
//printLog();
////printLog();
```

is it possible to replace "printLog();" into "//printLog();" but not "printLog();" originally in "//printLog();"?

Answer (score 1):

You could anchor your search pattern to the beginning of the line:

```
:%s@^printLog@//&
```

and maybe take leading white space into account for more safety:

```
:%s@^\s*printLog@//&
```

Breaking it down…

- `:s` allows you to use other characters than forward slashes as separators, that's handy when your search pattern or replacement contain forward slashes. Here I use `@` but you can use any character except `a-zA-Z0-9\"|`. See `:help e146`.
- The `^` atom represents the beginning of the line so `^printLog` will only match `printLog` if it is at the beginning of a line. See `:help /^`.
- In the "safe" variant, we add "zero or more white space characters" (`\s*`) between the beginning of the line and `printLog`. See `:help \s`.
- In the replacement part, we reuse the matched text with `&`. See `:help s/\&`.